# Setting up authorization: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mongoose

I try to make an authorization for my page where I'm currently trying to setup the login page for the user, using `mongoose`, `express`, `bcrypt` and `nodejs`. Unfortunately when I am trying to enter name and password I get the following error message:

> XHRPOSThttp://localhost:3000/api/register
> [HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 48ms]
> Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

My code for **login.js** looks the following:

```
router.get('/',  async (req, res) => {
    //const articles = await Object.values(ArticlesWeb.articles).filter(all => all.publish ==='True');
    //res.render('futureweb', {articles: articles});
    res.render('login')
});

router.post('/api/register', async (req, res) => {
    res.json({status: 'ok'})

    if(!username || typeof username !== 'string'){
        return res.json({status: 'error', error: 'Invalid username'})
    }

    if(!password || typeof username !== 'string'){
        return res.json({status: 'error', error: 'Invalid password'})
    }

    if (password.length < 5){
        return res.json({
            status: 'error',
            error: 'Password is too short. Password should at least have 6 characters.'
        })
    }

    const password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)

    try {
        const response = await User.create({
            username,
            password})
        } catch (error) {
            if (error.code === 11000){
                //duplicate key
                return res.json({status: 'error', error: 'Username already in use'})
            }
            throw error
            console.log(error)
            
        }
    }
)
```

The code for **login.ejs** file includes the part where I fetch the json data from my POST request:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="reg-form">
        <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Form"/>
    </form>
    <script>
        const form = document.getElementById('reg-form')
        form.addEventListener('submit', registerUser)

        // 1. Send data as JSON - favored in node.js
        //2 send data as urlencoded - very popular in PHP
        async function registerUser(event) {
            event.preventDefault()
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value

            const result = await fetch('/api/register', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({
                    username, password
                }))
            }).then((res) => res.json())


        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anybody hint to me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Your are almost near. try this one make sure don't use parse and stringify same time.

```
 const result = await fetch('/api/register', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username, password
            })
        }).then((res) => res.json())
        .then(data => console.log("data is here -> ", data))
```